# How to create nodeJS API with Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm new to firebase part and I've one requirement to use firebase as a part of serverless architecture, below mentioned is something I need to do, can expertly guide me what to choose from firebase to achieve the same.

1. I want to create restful API using firebase with NodeJs with an express module of the node, is it something possible or any alternative way to achieve the same using nodejs?
2. I want to use the firebase authentication mechanism with nodejs code part, ultimately want to create API using the nodeJS with firebase to authenticate the user, so what to use from firebase to achieve the same?
3. There would be straight forward API that I want to create including the authentication and data store in cloud using firebase, here do I need to use either firestore or real-time database?

I want to deploy the nodeJs project using firebase with firebase cloud, can give me some more details on like how we can do that, reference link sharing would be appreciated.

I had a basic look into few stuff like firebase client SDK, firebase admin SDK, not sure in my case whether I would require to use client SDK or admin SDK to create restFul API.

Note: I want to use no SQL data base, where various collection I can create and can use the same using firebase, I checked that and firestore would perform the same thing, like to store the JSON data, but wanted to know is there any other way to store data or firestore is the best option?

I checked somewhere on reference link about the cloud function, this function can be triggered based on some event, including some https request trigger as well, wanted to confirm using cloud function to create restful API is the good approach or what is the best way to create API using firebase.

Comment: please ask one question at a time :)

Comment: Sure, next time will take care of this, thank you @jsRook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create restful API using firebase with NodeJs with express module of node, is it something possible or any alternative way to achieve the same using nodejs?

Yes it is possible

> I want to use the firebase authentication mechanism with nodejs code part, ultimately want to create API using the nodeJS with firebase to authenticate the user, so what to use from firebase to achieve the same?

You can use firebase SDK for authentication

> There would be straight forward API that I want to create including the authentication and data store in cloud using firebase , here do I need to use either firestore or real time data base?

If you are asking of the database, then you can use any database of your choice, wheater it is MongoDB, firebase-realtime-database etc

Comment: Umm how to configure MongoDB with firebase? as currently I can see realtime db or firestore in firebase dashboard.

Comment: Ok so firebase admin sdk would be use for user authentication?

Comment: I believe, using cloud function we can create the restful API, so with combination of express and cloud function we can create the restful API right? or any other good approach to create restful API?

Comment: yes you can use cloud function to create restful api and use fire realtime db